# redirect to other page if click on leave page

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

How can i redirect him if a user clicks on leave a page button on onbeforeunload. Please check my code

```
function openNewWindow() {
    window.open('http://google.com/','_blank');
    window.focus();
}
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {

   event = event || window.event;
   var confirmClose = 'Are you sure?'; 
   if (event) {
       event.returnValue = confirmClose;
       if(confirmClose)
       {
           if(true)
           {
       openNewWindow();

           }

       }

       return confirmClose; 

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the users chooses yes in the onbeforeunload dialog then he will leave the page, you can not  prevent this. You can however do some things before the dialog shows, like you are doing in your code, but the dialog it self is only displayed AFTER your function executes, displaying the return value.

Your code seems a bit obscure to, what are you expecting from  `if(confirmClose)`, this will always evaluate to true because a non empty string is "truthy" in javascript.